# Display selected text of TextBox from beginning

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I have a simple silverlight application with a textbox and a button, when text length exceeds the width of textbox, the selected text always display the end part of the text, is it possible to display text from the beginning while having the text selected?

I have tried setting SelectionStart to 0 but it doesn't work, by setting SelectionLength to 0 will display from the beginning, but the text is not selected/highlighted.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = "very looooooooooong text";
    textBox1.SelectAll();
    textBox1.Focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **CaretIndex** property of textbox.
Like textBox.CaretIndex = 0;

Comment: this just set cursor to the beginning, the text is not selected. also silverlight doesn't have this property